# Final form Field with type=checkbox not work with format props

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-final-form, final-form

I found that format does not work when we use in the type=checkbox Field.

I have this snippet for example

```
 <Field
       name="gender"
       component="input"
       type="checkbox"
       format={value => {
          return false
       }}
       parse={v => (v ? "foo" : "bar")}
/>
```

Following this example, the checkbox should always be unchecked because I force it to false in format props, but I can still toggle the check status of checkbox

Comment: This sounds VERY related to this PR that was released today in v6.5.2. Try again with new version?
https://github.com/final-form/react-final-form/pull/859

Comment: @Erik R. Awesome, that release resolved this issue. Thank you